# Limiting the scope of a transaction in Apache Camel

Tags: scope, transactions, apache-camel

I have a transacted Camel route with a number of processors

```
from(Constant.RouteA)
   .transacted()
   .process(processor1)
   .process(processor2)
   .process(processor3)
   .wireTap(Constant.RouteB)
   .wireTap(Constant.RouteC)
   .end()
```

My problem is that I don't want the final part of the route (the wiretaps) to be part of the transaction i.e. I want them to be executed once processor3 has finished and the transaction committed.

Initially I looked at using onCompletion() but it doesn't seem to work together with transacted().

So I found another way which requires using policy() to limit the transaction scope i.e.

```
from(Constant.RouteA)
   .policy("PROPAGATION_REQUIRED")
      .process(processor1)
      .process(processor2)
      .process(processor3)
   .end()
   .wireTap(Constant.RouteB)
   .wireTap(Constant.RouteC)
   .end()
```

The problem is that this solution requires to define the SpringTransactionPolicy in the Spring configuration, but the software I'm working on doesn't use Spring. Transactions are managed by Bitronix and everything works just by using the transacted() method, which as far as I can tell doesn't allow you to limit the scope of a transaction.

Is there a simple way to achieve my goal? Hopefully without bringing Spring into the picture. Thank you!

Comment: Actually, you are using Spring for managing transaction right now. Spring-tx works as proxy between Camel and TransactionManager and is registered because you have transacted() in route. SpringTransactionPolicy is in use too, though you dont see it. Why the fear of SpringTransactionPolicy ? You can pass your preffered transaction manager in constructor of it

Comment: I've tried that, created a new SpringTransactionPolicy and then tried to call on it setTransactionManager(tranManager), but my tranManager is a bitronix.tm.BitronixTransactionManager which cannot be cast to org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager

Comment: Never worked with Bitronix, but have you tried [this](https://github.com/muellerc/camel-in-transaction/blob/master/src/test/resources/META-INF/spring/JmsAndJdbcXATransactionSampleWithBitronixTest-context.xml) example? In Java it could be `new SpringTransactionPolicy(new JtaTransactionManager(tranManager,tranManager))`

Comment: Thank you Bedla! That compiles. However accordingly to my documentation the next step is to insert the "PROPAGATION_REQUIRED" key in the Registry, but my Registry is of type org.apache.camel.spi.Registry, which hasn't got the put method (unlike SimpleRegistry). Anyway this is becoming more time consuming than I expected to and I will have to give up and move on with other tasks. Thanks for your help though, much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Try to create two routes. For example:

```
from(direct:startRoute)
      .to(Constant.RouteA)
      .wireTap(Constant.RouteB)
      .wireTap(Constant.RouteC);

from(Constant.RouteA)
      .transacted()
      .process(processor1)
      .process(processor2)
      .process(processor3);
```

Once route "Constant.RouteA" is finished all changes will committed.

Comment: That's interesting, although the wireTap won't wait for RouteA to complete. However if I mix your solution with the onCompletion() I might get what I need.

Comment: It's strange. "Direct"-component provides synchronous invocation. WireTap should handle the message after "Constant.RouteA" will be done. Only after that wireTape forward message to another chanel. Perhaps you use asynchronous requests?